# My table is outputting incorrect values for the percentage

Tags: java, arrays, percentage

```
public class apples {

private static String[] level1 = new String[] { "A", "B", "I", "K", "N", "O", "P", "S", "T", "W" };



public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] scores1 = { 99, 80, 56, 88, 70, 35, 67, 60, 78, 56 };

        int[] correct1 = {20, 20, 13, 15, 22, 18, 19, 21, 23, 25};

        int[] incorrect1 = {2, 1, 5, 2, 2, 5, 8, 1, 0, 0};


        double[] percentage1 = new double[correct1.length];
        for(int a = 0; a < correct1.length; a++ ){ 
                 percentage1[a] = (double)((correct1[a] / (correct1[a] + incorrect1[a]))*100);
            }


        System.out.println("Character \t Correct \t Incorrect \t Percentage");
            for(int counter = 0; counter<scores1.length;counter++){
                System.out.println(level1[counter] + "\t\t " + correct1[counter] + "\t\t " + incorrect1[counter] + "\t\t " + percentage1[counter]);
            }


}

}
```

This outputs a table with 4 headings. The character, correct and incorrect columns show as expected. However the percentage row is not working properly. For example, character 'A', correct 20 and incorrect 2 gives a percentage of 0.0. Any 'incorrect' value > 0 outputs a percentage value of 0, and any 'incorrect' value which = 0 gives a percentage value of 100 (which is correct)... Can someone please explain where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are dealing with integers here, and for integer division, the result is truncated. You'll need to cast the original values to double instead, or multiply one part by `1.0` to get it as a double:

```
percentage1[a] = ((correct1[a]*1.0 / (correct1[a] + incorrect1[a]))*100);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! and to the others who also answered. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
 percentage1[a] = (double)((correct1[a] / (correct1[a] + incorrect1[a]))*100);
```

The above code casts to a `double` *after* the calculation is competed.

To cast as part of the calculation, use:

```
percentage1[a] = (( ((double)correct1[a]) / (correct1[a] + incorrect1[a]))*100);
```

Answer (score 1):

You calculations here

```
 percentage1[a] = (double)((correct1[a] / (correct1[a] + incorrect1[a]))*100);
```

perform integer division (you just cast them afterwards to `double`). If you want them to return the actual floating point division result, you have to cast all operands to double *before* the calculation.

So the fastest option would be to change this:

```
    double[] correct1 = {20, 20, 13, 15, 22, 18, 19, 21, 23, 25};

    double[] incorrect1 = {2, 1, 5, 2, 2, 5, 8, 1, 0, 0};
```

Another would be to change the computation to something like this

```
percentage1[a] = (1.0 * correct1[a] / (correct1[a] + incorrect1[a]))*100;
```

or to simplify a little:

```
percentage1[a] = 100.0 * correct1[a] / (correct1[a] + incorrect1[a]);
```